# How is this approximation derived?

Tags: approximation

What is the argument behind: 1/(1+x) can be approximated by 1-x if x<<1 ?

I couldn't find where this approximation comes from/derived.

Comment: Taylor expanding $\frac{1}{1+x}$ around $x=0$ and retaining only first term.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Try long division

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because near $0$ we have\begin{align}\frac1{1+x}&=1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots\text{ (it's the sum of a geometric series)}\\&\simeq1-x.\end{align}